# can timestampadd be used to add intervals to times?

Tags: mysql

timestampadd is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) as adding to dates or datetimes; since mysql 5.6 it appears to also work on times, returning a time rather than a datetime, but I hesitate to use that without seeing it documented.  Can anyone show if this is supported behavior?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1affbe7f1f93411270d21c710563f098)

Comment: I would raise a bug report on mysql's site saying that according to the documentation the function should not work with time data type and you will get an authorative answer.

Comment: Should be reported as a bug (which may be documented as a feature). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ce5daff6f72f9b849297ea0e2eaeba7

Comment: When seen in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0aebf5ddd211f8e3295633b63f166a0a) it is a feature with a need for documenting, because some peeps might say that `timestampadd(minute,723,time(120000))` should not return `24:03:00`, but want/need something like `1 00:03:00`